# How to use the access_token until its expiration and then get and use a new one with the refresh_token?

Tags: php, api, token, access-token

For getting connected to an API endpoint, it is necessary to include in the request a token, which should be received before.

**Example**:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://api.mysite/v2/orders \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'
```

**In PHP this will look like this:**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mysite/v2/orders');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');    

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer <token>';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response, true);
...
```

**Authorization (OAuth2)**

Fetch access token

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.mysite/v1/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'username=<YourUsername>&password=<YourPassword>&grant_type=password&client_id=token-mysite-api'
```

**PHP version:**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mysite/v1/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=<YourUsername>&password=<YourPassword>&grant_type=password&client_id=token-mysite-api");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response, true);
$access_token = $result['access_token'];
$refresh_token = $result['refresh_token'];
```

**The response looks like this:**

```
{
"access_token": "<access tocken>",
"expires_in": 1800,
"refresh_expires_in": 7200,
"refresh_token": "<refresh tocken>",
"token_type": "bearer",
"not-before-policy": 0,
"session_state": "916a880a-9dae...",
"scope": "pumba-roles-app-portal partner email profile"
}
```

Once the access token is expired should be used the refresh token to get a new access token, without using users credentials again:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.mysite/v1/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'refresh_token=<refresh_token>&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=token-mysite-api'
```

**PHP version:**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mysite/v1/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "refresh_token=<refresh_token>&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=token-mysite-api");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response, true);
...
```

The response from refresh is the same as from getting token (see it above).

**My question is:**

How to do the verification and get the correct token? If the `access_token` is not expired > use it again. If it is expired > use the `refresh_token` for getting the new `access_token` and use it. Repeat this action for the next requests.

I spent much time trying different approaches but with each request, I get always new token.

Waiting for your help, please :).

Comment: Store the response from requesting the token and when that response was received. You can then use "expires_in" (which should be seconds) combined with the timestamp of response to determine whether the token is expired, and refresh if necessary.

Comment: @LennDolling "tocken" == token. It's pretty easy to decipher from context provided in the question, so I'm now sure what your comment is adding to the conversation?